# Custom routes with a different base URL in Cakephp using Router/HtmlHelper

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I'm running a CMS using CakePHP at an URL like `https://cms.example.com`

In the CMS, we have links to view/preview content entered on the site.  But the preview links are hosted on the front facing website: `http://www.example.com`.

I'm using the HtmlHelper::link() method to generate the URLs with reverse routing by sending it an array of parameters.  This works fine other than the fact that the base url is wrong. It looks like HtmlHelper is just some extra code wrapped around Router::url(), which does its own lookup of the 'base' url value.

Is there some easy way to override this value?  I have separate config files for each environment (dev, staging, production) that I can use to set a base url value for these types of links, but it doesn't appear that passing in 'base' does anything in the Router class.

I was considering overriding or creating an extra function extending HtmlHelper but if the route itself is handled by Router I'd now have to override/extend that instead, which seems like a mess.

HtmlHelper::link's $url parameter references `$this->url()` to parse the value.  There is no url() method in HtmlHelper, though.  It is inherited from the Helper class, where it is defined as:

```
public function url($url = null, $full = false) {
    return h(Router::url($url, $full));
}
```

So really, it's just a wrapper around `Router::url()`, which has no ability to modify the base url.  There is logic in Router to look up the base url, but no ability for the user to modify it without overloading Router.

Comment: it will be helpfull if you will provide sourcecode